# File lprodump missing after installing Qt6 and using LinguistTools in CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6, qt-linguist

I've encountered an issue while setting up a Qt6 project with CMake on Linux Mint.
Despite successful installation of Qt6 and its components, I'm facing a problem with `Qt6LinguistTools`.
Specifically, when I use `find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED LinguistTools)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`, CMake generates an error indicating that the `lprodump` file is missing.

Here's the error message I receive:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsTargets.cmake:131 (message):
  The imported target "Qt6::lprodump" references the file

     "/usr/lib/qt6/libexec/lprodump"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt6LinguistTools/Qt6LinguistToolsTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.
```

I've tried reinstalling Qt6 and its components, but the file still does not appear in the expected directory.

Is there a specific package in Linux Mint (Ubuntu) that contains the `lprodump` file for Qt6, or is there a known workaround for this issue?

Everything was working correctly before, and I haven't knowingly changed anything in my setup that would cause this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue with the missing `lprodump` file, install the `qt6-tools-dev-tools`.

Use the following command:

```
sudo apt install qt6-tools-dev-tools
```

This should address the missing file problem.

---

To verify that the file is indeed in the package, you can use the `dpkg` utility:

```
dpkg -L qt6-tools-dev-tools
```

Output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/qt6
/usr/lib/qt6/bin
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/pixeltool
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdbus
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdbusviewer
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qdistancefieldgenerator
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtdiag
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtdiag6
/usr/lib/qt6/bin/qtplugininfo
/usr/lib/qt6/libexec
/usr/lib/qt6/libexec/lprodump
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/qt6-tools-dev-tools/copyright
```

As seen, the file is presented in the list.